# SonarQube, Use existing widget in my own global dashboard

Tags: widget, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I want to create my own global dashboard in a new SonarQube Plugin. So, I have created a new class in my java project that extend **DashboardTemplate**.

My problem is the following : I want to add to my dashboard an existing widget (**MeasureFilterListWidget**). I want that the widget display it automatically when I add my plugin to SonarQube, it's for why I don't use the manual method.

In the next image, I want to add the widget class in the place of "???".
[image]

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

As per Javadoc of [addWidget](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.4/apidocs/org/sonar/api/web/Dashboard.html#addWidget(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> The widget ids are listed by the web service /api/widgets

Let's do this on the public SonarQube instance (Nemo): [list widgets](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/widgets). This is what you're looking for:

```
{
  "id": "measure_filter_list",
  "title": "Measure Filter as List",
  "description": "Displays the result of a pre-configured measure filter as a list.",
   "categories": [ "Filters" ]
}
```

So you should replace the `???` by `measure_filter_list`.

Note that `addWidget` returns a [Dashboard.Widget](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.4/apidocs/org/sonar/api/web/Dashboard.Widget.html) to pre-define the widget's properties (e.g. the Measure Filter to use) and avoid manual configuration.